# Create google map with sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

So I'm trying to modify a map that I've created. I'd like to add a sidebar and I want it to center on clicking. Like this -> http://marcgrabanski.com/resources/jquery-google-maps/tutorial-part1.html

Here's my code so far

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%; 
        margin: 0; 
        padding: 0
      }
    </style>
    
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?KEY=AIzaSyCo0yGy0Qk9b1x4pFDnk_rMQibhBroLW8M"></script>
    <script>

  function initialize() {

    var locations = [
      ['<b><a href="#RSVP"><span style="font-size: large;">RSVP</span></a></b>', 6.428073, 3.421507, 1],
      ['<b><a href="#Izanagi"><span style="font-size: large;">Izanagi</span></a></b>', 6.426412, 3.414347, 2],
      ['<b><a href="#Bistro7"><span style="font-size: large;">Bistro 7</span></a></b>', 6.433162, 3.423306, 3],
      ['<b><a href="#SpiceRoute"><span style="font-size: large;">Spice Route</span></a></b>', 6.429500, 3.420479, 4],
      ['<b><a href="#355"><span style="font-size: large;">355</span></a></b>', 6.428518, 3.428305, 5]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      scrollwheel: false,
      draggable: true,
      zoom: 14,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(6.456528,3.408272),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    
    var iconBase = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal2/';

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon: iconBase + 'icon44.png'
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

EDIT: I made something (code pasted) and I want to transform it into another (link pasted). I'm asking for directions on how to.

Comment: What is the problem?  I don't see any sidebar or attempt at one in your code.  [example map with sidebar](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map2.html)

Comment: I haven't made an attempt because I don't know how to. I made something (code pasted) and I want to transform it into another (link pasted). I'm asking for directions on how to. That is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example that you linked to, the way that the map moves on click is done here (the comments are mine):

```
// looping through each marker, creating a li
$(markers).each(function(i,marker){
$("<li />")
    .html("Point "+i)
// calling the displayPoint() function on click
    .click(function(){
        displayPoint(marker, i);
    })
    .appendTo("#list");

GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function(){
    displayPoint(marker, i);
});
});

$("#message").appendTo(map.getPane(G_MAP_FLOAT_SHADOW_PANE));
```

...

```
// the displayPoint() function calls map.panTo, which will pan to the marker
map.panTo(marker.getLatLng());
```

[Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qn430qqk/) that uses your code with some updates from the site you linked

Comment: you are very welcome. If the answer was helpful to you, then feel free to upvote and mark it as your answer =)

Comment: quick thing: is there a way to edit the default bullet thing on the sidebar?

Comment: edit it how? you can make the text whatever you want, and style it however you want. eg. this css will remove the bullet decoration from the li:
  `list-style: none;`